# Haskell typeclasses: type error

Tags: json, parsing, haskell, types, typeclass

I am trying to write a little toy JSON parser. To do this I made a `Value` type that represents valid JSON values and a typeclass `Deserial a` that represents the ability of the type a to be deserialized from the `Value` type to the type `a`.

However, when I try to run the `deserialize` function on my type I am getting a type error:

```
No instance for (Deserial a0) arising from a use of deserialize
The type variable a0 is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there is a potential instance available:
  instance Deserial Person -- Defined at json.hs:33:10
In the expression: deserialize jason
In an equation for `deserialized': deserialized = deserialize jason
```

I know the logic of the deserialization is working because the "non typeclass version" is working. However, I am new to haskell and not sure what I'm doing wrong with my definition of the Deserial typeclass. Any help would be appreciated!

```
import System.IO
import Control.Applicative
import Data.Maybe


data Value = Str String 
           | Number Double
           | Boo Bool 
           | Object [(String, Value)]
           | Array [Value] 
           | Null deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

class Deserial a where
    deserialize :: Value -> Maybe a


data Person = Person String Double deriving (Show)

makePerson name age = case age of 
    Number n -> Just (Person name n)
    _ -> Nothing

instance Deserial Person where
    deserialize v = case v of
        Object [(name, age)] -> makePerson name age
        _ -> Nothing

getString (Str s) = s

getNumber (Number n) = Just n
getNumber _ = Nothing


main = do
    let jason = Object[("TestName", Number 3)]
    let _deserialized = _deserialize jason 
    --this next line does not compile 
    let  deserialized = deserialize jason
```

Comment: You need to do something to indicate what type the result of deserialization should have. This could be done at the use site, or you could use `let deserialized = deserialize jason :: Maybe Person`.

Comment: This did it thanks! Do we have to specify the type here because we are returning our typeclass parameter (ie: Maybe a) and so by specifying what 'a' is we are telling the compiler which instance of deserialize to use?

Comment: Yeah, pretty much. You don't always have to specify it explicitly--if you were to pass it to a function expecting a `Person` then type inference would do the job for you--but *something* needs to fix it to determine the instance, yeah.

Comment: Hm. There should be at least one duplicate of this, given the problems that usually arise with `read :: (Read a) => String -> a`.

Comment: @dfeuer you should submit your comment as an answer.